# Search button to search my Rails 3 site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am creating a site using rails 3.2 and for my layouts using twitter-bootstrap which I am still getting familiar with. I inputed a search button from twitter-bootstrap on my home page. I am trying to figure out how to make it so that search button will search the whole site i have set up not just specific items. Is there a way to have this search button to create a search for anything on the site just by typing in a word or specific item? I can't seem to find good way to do this. Thanks any guidence will be appreciated. I am using the below search box from twitter bootstrap.

```
 <form class="navbar-search pull-left">
 <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">
 </form>
```

Comment: Have you done any research on this at all? What have you found out?

Comment: I have done a little searching on this yes, but what I am finding is only pertaining to searching specific database tables or models and I want to be able to search the whole site. Maybe when I am searching I am using the wrong words. I found Paginate with AJAX, search logic and few other gems to use but only seem for specific searchin on models or tables. I will keep looking and see what I can find. Thanks!

Comment: You will need a plugin like Sunspot, Ferret, or Xapian. Try putting those in your search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support search on a Rails site, you will need an indexing and searching plugin such as Ferret (not sure this is still supported), Xapian (requires some setup) or Sunspot (a bridge to Apache's Solr). Once you have the plugin, you will need to define which models you are searching, how often to index, and issues like that; this is a very broad category. Hopefully the (not comprehensive) plugins listed above will give you a starting point.

There isn't an out-of-the-box solution for searching The Whole Site because it's almost certain there are parts of the site you don't want indexed and findable in a search. User data, for example, may or may not be useful as search results.

Comment: Thank you! That will give me a good start point. Much apprecitate!